# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean, using Table.addRow() with Jackcess

Tags: java, string, ms-access, boolean, jackcess

I am trying to write some values in a MS Access database using Jackcess. My values are originally represented using String. The code I am using is the following:

```
int nColumns = 0;

// get table from internal representation
ModelDatabaseTable table = this.DB.getTable(tableName);

// create new table
TableBuilder DBTableBuilder = new TableBuilder(tableName);

// get table's columns and their Jackcess datatype    
Map<String, DataType> columns = table.getColumns();

// for each column, insert it in the actual database
for (String columnName : columns.keySet()) {
    DataType dt = columns.get(columnName);
    ColumnBuilder cb = new ColumnBuilder(columnName).setType(dt);
    if (dt.isVariableLength()) {
        cb.setMaxLength();
    }
    DBTableBuilder.addColumn(cb);
    nColumns += 1;
}

// if columns were inserted
if (nColumns > 0) {
    // write table to actual database
    Table DBTable = DBTableBuilder.toTable(this.DBConnection);

    // for each row
    for (ModelDatabaseRow row : table.getRows()) {

        // get list of values (represented using String)
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

        // for each column get its value and insert it in values
        for (String columnName : columns.keySet()) {
            String columnValue = row.getColumn(columnName);
            values.add(columnValue);
        }

        // print current row
        System.out.println(values.toString());

        // insert row in database table. Exception rises here:
        // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
        DBTable.addRow(values.toArray());
    }
}
```

A basic example which does not work is the following (routine data is described using JSON). In this case the routine stops when trying to insert BOOLEAN values (`HasM`, `HasZ`) but it is able to insert DOUBLE values - which are all given as parameters to `Table.addRow()` function as a String array.

```
{
  "tables": {
    "Table1": {
      "rows": [
      {
        "items": {
        "ExtentBottom": "45.050715999999994",
        "ExtentLeft": "7.644834000000003",
        "ExtentRight": "7.670400999999998",
        "ExtentTop": "45.07392899999999",
        "FieldName": "Shape",
        "HasM": "false",
        "HasZ": "false",
        "IdxGridSize": "3.7252903001966386E-7",
        "IdxOriginX": "0.0",
        "IdxOriginY": "0.0",
        "MHigh": "NaN",
        "MLow": "NaN",
        "SRID": "1",
        "ShapeType": "4",
        "TableName": "GDB_Items",
        "ZHigh": "NaN",
        "ZLow": "NaN"
        }
      },
      {
        "items": {
        "ExtentBottom": "4989476.8181",
        "ExtentLeft": "393329.1171000004",
        "ExtentRight": "395300.25320000015",
        "ExtentTop": "4992023.569399999",
        "FieldName": "Shape",
        "HasM": "false",
        "HasZ": "false",
        "IdxGridSize": "0.009311329524584121",
        "IdxOriginX": "0.0",
        "IdxOriginY": "0.0",
        "MHigh": "NaN",
        "MLow": "NaN",
        "SRID": "2",
        "ShapeType": "4",
        "TableName": "Building_DIMMER_01",
        "ZHigh": "NaN",
        "ZLow": "NaN"
        }
      }
      ],
      "columns": {
      "ExtentBottom": "DOUBLE",
      "ExtentLeft": "DOUBLE",
      "ExtentRight": "DOUBLE",
      "ExtentTop": "DOUBLE",
      "FieldName": "TEXT",
      "HasM": "BOOLEAN",
      "HasZ": "BOOLEAN",
      "IdxGridSize": "DOUBLE",
      "IdxOriginX": "DOUBLE",
      "IdxOriginY": "DOUBLE",
      "MHigh": "DOUBLE",
      "MLow": "DOUBLE",
      "SRID": "LONG",
      "ShapeType": "LONG",
      "TableName": "TEXT",
      "ZHigh": "DOUBLE",
      "ZLow": "DOUBLE"
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

The preceding JSON represents the internal representation of data used by my program and it is structured in this way:

```
{
  "tables": {
    "TableName": {
      "rows": [
        {
          "items: {
            "columnName1": "columnValue1",
            ...
            "columnNameN": "columnValueN"
           }
        },
        {
          "items: {
            "columnName1": "columnValue1",
            ...
            "columnNameN": "columnValueN"
           }
        }
      ],
      "columns": {
        "columnName1": "columnDataType1",
        ...
        "columnNameN": "columnDataTypeN"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In case it is not clear ask me,

Thanks

Comment: The JSON boolean values are true and false (without the quotes) if that helps ...

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me. Parse the `Boolean` columns from `String` before attempting to insert them into your Access table. What isn't clear about the `Exception`? You mentioned that `Double` worked as you expected, but that's got to be how your database schema is defined (note, you did not post your schema).

Comment: @Johann-ChristophJacob Thanks, but in this case all data types are represented as String (I used JSON only to visualize them).. @ElliottFrisch The fact that is not clear to me is that numbers `LONG` and `DOUBLE` are automatically parsed from their String representation, `BOOLEAN` are not. Yes, I did not post the schema because I am not able to create it right now. However, the data types of the field are presented at the end of the second code section. Tell me if it is not clear..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackcess normally expects to work with strongly-typed Java objects. In this case Jackcess must be trying to be helpful by automatically converting a `String` to a `Double` when adding the Row. For whatever reason, Jackcess is *not* willing to automatically convert a `String` to a `Boolean`<sup>*****</sup>, even if that conversion seems obvious (to us), so for a table with fields

ID: AutoNumber, Primary Key
DoubleField: Numeric(Double)
YesnoField: Yes/No

the following code will throw the exception you are seeing

```java
String doubleFieldValue = "3.14159";
String yesnoFieldValue = "true";
tbl.addRow(Column.AUTO_NUMBER, doubleFieldValue, yesnoFieldValue);
```

However, this will work

```java
String doubleFieldValue = "3.14159";
String yesnoFieldValue = "true";
tbl.addRow(Column.AUTO_NUMBER, doubleFieldValue, Boolean.parseBoolean(yesnoFieldValue));
```

As a general rule it is best to try and use objects of the correct type when working with Jackcess to avoid little "surprises" like this, so by rights we really should be using

```java
String doubleFieldValue = "3.14159";
String yesnoFieldValue = "true";
tbl.addRow(Column.AUTO_NUMBER, Double.parseDouble(doubleFieldValue), Boolean.parseBoolean(yesnoFieldValue));
```

<sup>*****</sup> **Edit: 2015-03-21**

Automatic conversion of `String` values to `Boolean` was added to Jackcess 2.0.9, released today.

Answer (score 2):

In case of SharedPreferences this exception arise for using the same key word for boolean and string in SharedPreferences, here is my [Details Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66089527/7608371)

Comment: Thank you, this was problem from my side.

Answer (score 0):

On the line:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
```

you specifically specify you want values to only contain String objects,
if you want to insert Booleans you need a more generic object declaration.

```
List<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

though you'll probably lose some needed string functionality.

Comment: hmm, well its kind of hacky but you could, on the line before you insert, test the bool condition and depending on the case, insert a string 'true' or 'false' instead? 

edit: i see you are inserting 2 booleans, in that case* a 4 way switch startement (true,true.......False,False) and insert the strings. hacky but should get you going.


*heh