# SharedPreferences - java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm confused with an exception that is thrown for something that shouldn't.
The error is the following:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

But, my code doesn't try to cast a Boolean to String Ô_o
Is it possible that the compiler is wrong in indicating where the exception is coming from? I'm using an Huawei

**This part triggers the exception:**

```
if(SharedPreferencesManager.getUserMRZ(ScanEUID.this).equals("0")
&& SharedPreferencesManager.getUserDocumentIdFront(ScanEUID.this) != null 
&& SharedPreferencesManager.getUserDocumentIdBack(ScanEUID.this) != null)
{
```

**The associated methods are the following**

```
public static String getUserMRZ(Context context){
    return getSharedPreferences(context).getString(Constants.USER_HAS_MRZ, "0");
}
public static String getUserDocumentIdFront(Context context) {
    return getSharedPreferences(context).getString(Constants.USER_DOCUMENT_ID_FRONT, null);
}
public static String getUserDocumentIdBack(Context context) {
    return getSharedPreferences(context).getString(Constants.USER_DOCUMENT_ID_BACK, null);
}
```

The setMRZ method

```
public static void setUserMRZ(Context context, String has_mrz){
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(context).edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.USER_HAS_MRZ, has_mrz);
        editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: If there's ever been a string with that key (USER_HAS_MRZ), even if by accident, it will stay there until you clear the app's data or reinstall. Try reinstalling it to see if it still occurs.

Comment: Check where you are first creating the USER_HAS_MRZ preference. You are probably informing a boolean value.

Comment: Uninstalled it and unfortunately same error. So weird.

Comment: Thank you @Jonas452 - I just updated my question to add the method that set it. So I have 3 usages and the first is : "SharedPreferencesManager.setUserMRZ(identityCheck.this, "0");"

Answer (score 5):

Check your setters, I just had the same issue and I discovered that I'd mistakenly done a bad copy/pasta and used the Key for that value in a setter for a Boolean value...

Comment: You saved my mental and about half of an hour of my time... Really thanks a lot.

Comment: If the app you've installed is using a boolean preference and you now want it to be a String, you must reinstall your app.

Answer (score 2):

In My case I was wrongly used the same shared preference key for different Activity, For putString and putBoolean. Though the problem arise. I used an activity as :

```
editor.putString("fezilalilquran", "on");
```

And Another Activity I used :

```
editor.putBoolean("fezilalilquran", true);
```

So, you see that, for the same key word for boolean and string in Shared Preferences,  When I want to get the boolean in MainActivity, so the cast exception arise for this line :

```
boolean isTafseerOn = settings.getBoolean("fezilalilquran", true);
```

So, replacing the line in settings Activity, from :

```
editor.putString("fezilalilquran", "on");
```

to :

```
editor.putBoolean("fezilalilquran", true);
```

solved my issue:

Happy coding...... .

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

If your value of Constants.USER_HAS_MRZ is Boolean, you should use `getBoolean` method

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean)

Comment: I'm sure the OP is aware which method to use, it is described that only Strings are stored with the `setUserMRZ()` method

Comment: @Isabelle are you sure that exception had thrown in the `SharedPreferencesManager.getUserMRZ(ScanEUID.this).equals("0")` line?

Comment: If I refer to what the compiler mentions, yes.

Comment: @Isabelle did you try to run the application on another device? Show error stacktrace.

Comment: Doing it right now, and same error with big crash this time -_-

Comment: I guess thers is simple a mistake there, try to find all `Constants.USER_HAS_MRZ` usages, probably somewhere you put a boolean. And examine all preferences with https://facebook.github.io/stetho/ or Device File Explorer in AS 2.4

Comment: What about the full error stacktrace, can you show that?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and found that I used the same key twice (copy/paste error).

```
private const val PREF_IS_IMPERIAL ="imperial"
private const val PREF_LAST_CITY_SEARCH ="imperial"  //oops
```

Answer (score -3):

In my case, I just surround the get methods with Try Catch and it works!

Comment: It is not answering the question, instead it just tells to catch the exception.